# Point to Point remoting application

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, p2p

I have been using TeamViewer to connect to my home PC, its rather slow.

I would like an application that could connect to my computer directly via the internet, but without a server in between.

In this scenario only my internet connection would have to be fast right? I would like it to also have VOIP and chat capabilities like TeamViewer but that is not a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/)

> Who Should Use UltraVNC?
>
> - Individuals that want to ...  access
>     their home PC from work or cybercafes
>
> UltraVNC runs under Windows operating
>   systems (95, 98, Me, NT4, 2000, XP,
>   2003, Vista, Windows 7...). Its
>   embedded Java Viewer allows you to
>   connect (and make File transfers) from
>   a simple Web Browser on any system
>   supporting Java (Linux, Mac OS...) to
>   an UltraVNC server.

Comment: Is it very difficult to setup? and can it be setup to auto login